# How to install Debian on Acer Swift 3 SF314-42?

Tags: debian, system-installation, firmware, amd-graphics, iwlwifi

I have got Acer Swift 3 SF314-42-R7TJ (NX.HSEEU.00H) without an OS preinstalled. I made a Debian installation USB [following the manual](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.en.html#usb-copy-isohybrid). I tried different hybrid CD and DVD installation images, including images with non-free firmware. EFI immediately recognizes the installation media on boot. Debian installs, but on boot I get a black screen with a blinking white underscore (_). It seems to do not respond to keyboard. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This laptop comes with function keys working as "media" keys by default. You can either disable it in BIOS or add <kbd>Fn</kbd> to all usual combinations with the function keys. To access a command line press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

This laptop comes with AMD Ryzen 5 4500U processor with integrated AMD Radeon™ Graphics, which, in this case, is a Renoir APU. [According to Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=4500u-windows-linux), it is not supported in older Linux 5.4 kernel, but is supported in newer Linux 5.7 kernel. `firmware-amd-graphics` in Debian "buster" (current stable release) [does not support](https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-amd-graphics) Renoir. "buster" also has older kernel. Both, firmware and newer kernel are available in its backports:

```
# echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt update
# apt -t buster-backports install linux-image-amd64 firmware-amd-graphics
```

You can borrow and use a USB Ethernet adapter to connect the laptop to Internet. Alternatively, you can download individual packages from debian.org, copy them on a USB drive, mount it, and install with apt:

```
# apt install ./linux-image-5.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64_5.8.10-1~bpo10+1_amd64.deb ./firmware-amd-graphics_20200918-1~bpo10+1_all.deb
```

To make Wi-Fi working you will also need to install `firmware-iwlwifi` from backports. It has firmware, probably AX201, which enables the advertised Wi-Fi 6 2×2 MU-MIMO (Intel Wireless Wi-Fi 6 AX200) + Bluetooth 5.0.

In "buster", it will use CPU with LLVMpipe for graphics. It will be slow only for graphics-hungry tasks.

Alternatively, if you move to testing ("bullseye") or unstable ("sid"), it will pull in the necessary kernel and non-free firmware. They also come with newer version of Mesa, which uses the integrated graphics. Since a recent update, under "bullseye", I keep running into a bug with integrated speakers not working while headphones work just fine.

---

If after installation you get "No Bootable Device", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to reboot and then keep pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> during boot to get to UEFI setup. There, on the "*Security*" tab, you need to "*Set Supervisor Password*" first, then the option to "*Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing*" becomes available. (You can clear the password later by changing it to empty string.) The necessary file is under `HDD0` → `<EFI>` → `<debian>` → `<shimx64.efi>`. The boot description can be anything. If you perform a re-install and UEFI refuses to save the file complaining that the file already exists, then "*Erase all Secure Boot Setting*" first and exit with saving UEFI settings.